# Python cgi on OpenShift

Tags: python, cgi, openshift, wsgi

I just installed the python3.3 cartridge and I git pushed my "hello.py" file to the same folder as that wsgi.py file that always opens when I run my application in the browser. I created also a link within wsgi.py to my hello.py page.

But when I click on the link nothing happens.

Can openshift anyhow run plain cgi (so without flask, django, wsgi, ...) ? I also heared a lot of this .htacces file, so perhaps I should add/edit that file?

Also my links to static html pages are not working.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to just drop arbitrary `.py` files in the top level directory like that and have them handled as CGI scripts.

Why do you specifically need CGI? Why not convert it to use WSGI, which will perform a lot better than CGI.

There may be a convoluted way of doing it with the standard Apache setup for the Python cartridge, but the CGI scripts would need to be under a sub URL normally used for static files.

Another way would involve overriding the standard Apache setup by running mod_wsgi-express and customising how it is setup. But then the question still remains, why ignore a perfectly good WSGI server and use CGI if wanting to run Python code.

---

UPDATE 1

If you do not care what the URL is, place your CGI script in a directory 'wsgi/static'. Inside that same directory then create a `.htaccess` file containing:

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
```

If the CGI script file was called 'hello.cgi', it would then be accessed with sub URL, joined to appropriate http://hostname for your site. Thus 'http://hostname/static/hello.cgi'.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice on converting my existing cgi app to wsgi. However, my main question is regarding the fact that my python seems not to be accessibele or gets interpreted? What else should I do to make it run?

Comment: So you still want to be able to run your CGI script? Do you care what URL it is under?

Comment: I did some reading on WSGI & Flask and I will do the conversion of my existing app to those during the upcoming weeks. I was just hoping that there is An easy way to deploy my existing cgi version also to Openshift. I already found the static folder, so perhaps I can deploy it overthere... ? It is not really important which URL...

Comment: Added update 1 above. It is quite possible that one may be able to have it appear to reside at a different URL through use of mod_rewrite rules which do an internal server redirect in a ``.htaccess`` file in the top directory of the project, but I need to experiment with that to verify it.

Comment: Thanks Graham. I will try it out! Johan

Comment: I was just able to add my cgi application under the static folder. thanks for the great advice !